# List of possible regions for X-AppEngine-Region

Tags: google-app-engine, geolocation, request-headers

The [GAE Docs on Request Headers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Request_Headers) say...

> **X-AppEngine-Region**
>
> Name of region from which the request originated. This value only
>   makes sense in the context of the country in X-AppEngine-Country. For
>   example, if the country is "US" and the region is "ca", that "ca"
>   means "California", not Canada.

Where can I get a list of all regions that could be returned? And why does it have to return "ca" when it can just return "California"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete list is in [ISO-3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) standard.
That's why it return "ca" and not 'California":  this is a standard like country codes.

Comment: I understand the ISO-3166-2 Standard. It's for Countries. That's *NOT* my question. My question is for regions. Where's the standard list for regions within countries? California is not a country. It's a region/state in the US. I want the standard list for regions.

Comment: @Albert No, as the Wikipedia article clearly states in the first sentence: "ISO 3166-2 is part of the ISO 3166 standard published by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO), and defines codes for the names of the principal subdivisions (e.g., provinces or states) of all countries coded in ISO 3166-1."

Comment: I'm so sorry. My mistake. Thanks so much!